# Watir with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, watir

I'm using watir in my Rails application.
I did simple commands and got a error:

```
  2.3.0 :001 > require 'watir-webdriver'
     /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require': `require "watir-webdriver"` is deprecated. Please, use `require "watir"`.
     => true 
  2.3.0 :002 > browser = Watir::Browser.new 

NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
from (irb):2:in `new'
from (irb):2
```

I need any help or suggestions on this point, thanks.
By default Watir is using chromedriver

Comment: What version of Watir are you using?

Comment: @JustinKo the version of watir is 6.16.5

Comment: did you read the error message? You need to `require "watir"` instead of using `watir-webdriver`

Comment: Does your Watir work correctly when just using Watir (ie no Rails)? Is there a more complete stack trace?

Comment: even with `require 'watir-webdriver'` cannot reproduce this error on ruby 2.6